# One parameter has the keys that exist on another parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a funciton whose definition looks this way:

```
const func = (array: {}[], object: {}) => {}
```

Keys of objects of `array` should include all the keys that exist on `object`.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do this:

```
type Dictionary<V> = {[k: string]: V};
const func = <T>(array: (Record<keyof T, any> & Dictionary<any>)[], object: T) => {};
```

You are making `func` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function which constrains `array` to be a type related to the type of `object`.  Specifically, it must be a `Record<keyof T, any>`, a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which has the same keys as `T` but any values.  I also added `Dictionary<any>` (a type with an [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html)) so that you won't get errors on extra keys in `array` (assuming you don't want errors for extra keys).  Let's see if it works:

```
func([{a: 1, b: true}], {a: "hey", b: "you"}); // okay
func([{a: 1}], {a: "hey", b: "you"}); // error, Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: number; }'
func([{a: 1, b: true, c: "1"}], {a: "hey", b: "you"}); // also okay because of Dictionary
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: It's a generic type parameter.  Read the [generics documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and let me know if it's still confusing you.

Comment: What was confusing me is that we use it to infer a type of a function with 2 params. The docs seem to be containing examples with only 1 param.

Comment: Why does "T" takes `object`'s type definition instead of `array`'s since it is the first parameter.

Comment: Type inference is an [involved process](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3117-type-inference).  The short answer is because `object`'s type is just `T`, whereas `array` is a complicated function of `T`, so `object` is given higher priority in type inference.

Comment: Thanks! Great link and a helpful answer!